# Visual Basic won't change regkey value

Tags: vb.net

So, I've been working on my program for 3 hours now (I'm new to VB),
so I've made the program to change the desktop wallpaper when a button is clicked, and it works fine, I want that as soon as you run the program as an administrator, that it changes the OEMBackground value is changed from 0 to 1,
but it won't work, why?

```
Imports System.Environment
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class Form_Main
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Theme, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Dim ChangeValue As Integer
        ChangeValue = 1
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background", "OEMBackground", ChangeValue)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Filepath As String
        Filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"
        My.Resources.Monika.Save("TranscodedWallpaper.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Filepath) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Filepath)
        End If
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("TranscodedWallpaper.jpg", Filepath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It did change it, no exception, just not the one you expected.  Project > Properties > Compile tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it when you tinker with registry keys that are affected by the [Registry Redirection feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot!